# Finding the minimum of a column depending the value of a second column

Tags: group-by, sqlite

I have (on sqlite) a table with the following structure :

| id | tile_id | creation_year | creation_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020 | 150 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020 | 132 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021 | 13 |
| 4 | 2 | 2020 | 15 |
| 5 | 3 | 2021 | 110 |
| 6 | 3 | 2021 | 18 |
| 7 | 3 | 2021 | 150 |

How can I transform  this table to a new table with the following structure :

| tile_id | count | min_date_id | max_date_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 6 | 7 |

I can't find a query that finds the smallest day for the first year (to build the third column) and the largest day of the largest year (to build the last column).

Comment: @ErgestBasha Indeed. Thanks, for the correction, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite 3.25+, you can use window functions for this, along with conditional aggregation

```
SELECT
  t.tile_id,
  COUNT(*) count,
  MIN(CASE WHEN t.rn = 1 THEN t.id END) min_date_id,
  MIN(CASE WHEN t.nextId IS NULL THEN t.id END) max_date_id
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tile_id ORDER BY creation_year, creation_day) AS rn,
      LEAD(id) OVER (PARTITION BY tile_id ORDER BY creation_year, creation_day) AS nextId
    FROM YourTable t
) t
GROUP BY
  t.tile_id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a17b56923d74311c7231095a83bebb7f)

You could also replace `LEAD` with a descending row-number, however that would require an extra sort

Comment: Thanks, it works very well and moreover it is usable on postgres without any modifications.